# Does a nullable foreign key always mean optional in ERD cardinality?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship, erd, cardinality

Suppose you have a `ticket` table and a `status` ticket. Below are their definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `priorities`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` INT NOT NULL,
    constraint `priorities_id_primary` Primary key (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tickets`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` Text NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `creatorId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `employeeId` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    `lastModified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `statusId` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    `priorityId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    constraint `tickets_id_primary` Primary key (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tickets_creatorid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`creatorId`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tickets_employeeid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`employeeId`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tickets_statusid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`statusId`) REFERENCES `statuses`(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tickets_priorityid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`priorityId`) REFERENCES `priorities`(`id`)
);
```

As you can see, the foreign key `statusId` is nullable. But when I use MySQL Workbench to draw the ERD, it shows the relationship as `One (and only one)` but I think it should be `Zero or one`. Doesn't the nullable dictate that or am I mistaken? Can we have a nullable foreign key with a `One (and only one)` relationship?

[image: ERD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nullable foreign key corresponds definitively to an optional relationship, that should be represented with `--|o-` and not `--||-`

This should be a bug. It may be related to the absence of `ON DELETE SET NULL` in your foreign key constraint (i.e. with your current constraint, it is not possible to delete the status if it is still used as a foreign key in ticket, which could be mis-interpreted as a mandatory relationship - which it is not).

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be a bug but I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried with the ON DELETE SET NULL to see if it changes anything in the resulting diagram?

Comment: Just tried it but got the same ERD. So I don't think it's the same. Interestingly, I sent the script for the entire DB that I wrote (and created this DB from) to my roommate, he ran it and created the diagram and his diagram was correct. Weird.